# Sharing session cookies accross different subdomains: is it possible to have 2 different active sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, session-cookies

In our app, an `Account` has many `User`s and each different account has a subdomain (e.g: `account.ourapp.com`)

We also reserve the subdomain `app` for ourselves as `app.ourapp.com` acts as a generic login from where a `User` can login to any account if the correct `subdomain`, `email` and `password` combinations are provided.

*generic login controller:*

```
class App::SessionsController < AppController
  def new
    @session_form = SessionForm.new
  end

  def create
    @session_form = SessionForm.new(params: session_params)
    if @session_form.save
      account = @session_form.account
      user = @session_form.user
      
      log_in user

      redirect_to admin_users_url(subdomain: account.subdomain)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def session_params
    params.require(:session_form).permit(:account_subdomain, :email, :password)
  end
end
```

Because the User session is created in `app.ourapp.com` but the User is redirected to `account.ourapp.com` after authentication, our `session_store` file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_ourapp_session',
                                       domain: :all,
                                       tld_length: 2
```

With the above configuration, the session created in the `app` subdomain is still valid for the `account` subdomain.

**The problem we are facing** is that some people using our app manage more than one account, and if Bob logs in to `firstaccount.ourapp.com` with the User `id 1` and then to `secondaccount.ourapp.com` with User `id 5` on the same computer, the first session is dropped and it's User is logged out.

Why is the first sessions dropped if the account subdomains and user id's are different?

Is it possible to share sessions across subdomains (so the session created in `app.ourapp.com` works for `account.ourapp.com`) but also have multiple sessions with different `User`s opened at the same time?

Comment: Not in the same browser.  If you are sharing a session across subdomains-- you are using ONE cookie, which is what allows you to share a session. You can: a) stop sharing sessions across subdomains, b) encourage the users to use different browsers if they need to log in simultaneously.

Comment: Instead of storing just one current user in the session, you could store a hash in the session that has the subdomain as a key and the current_user for that subdomain as a value. But keep in mind that you then have to give the user a choice what user to use on the shared subdomains, like `app` and `account`.